# How to display [woocommerce_my_account] shortcode in an html page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a folder with an html page in my theme folder, but it wont display woocommerce shortcodes in the html file, any one know how to display 
`<span class="pix_edit_text"> <?php echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]'); ?> </span>`
 in pages inside the theme folder, so it displays when users browse to the html page?

Comment: Do refer to this [page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/205992/how-to-create-a-shortcode-for-custom-page-template). It was a quick and easy search.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I repeat already tried things, I need to be sure of these before I can give a right answer.

1. Your template needs to be in php (.php), but it renders html.
2. Woocommerce template overwrites need to be in YourAwesomeTheme/woocommerce/* [the views that can be overwritten in WC](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/templates/myaccount)
3. Your theme needs to support Woocommerce. [Declaring WooCommerce Support](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/)
4. Your account page needs to set in WC settings [WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pages/).
5. I would not suggest adding the shortcode in a `<span>` tag.
6. Depending on what you are editing there, the solution may be fixed with these steps.

   1. page outside of WC structure,
   2. template that need to be assigned to a page
   3. DIVI page

Hope this put you in the right path to fix your problem.